# Telerik RadGrid Issue:No SelectedItems are shown on Buttonclick although few items are being selected

Tags: webforms, telerik, rad-controls

I have two RadGrids on my aspx page and have used one search TextBox to search items from the RadGrid.
There's a button on click of which the selected items are transferred to other grid.

The problem is when i search the items with particular key word and then select items from the RadGrid and click the button. No action is performed and in the code behint it shows no data items selected. Then if I again select from the searched list and click the button it works fine.

```
   function requestStart(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ButtonPrint") > 0 
            ||
            args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ButtonSelect") > 0
            )
            args.set_enableAjax(false);
    }


      <telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="EnrollmentPanel">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="EnrollmentPanel"      LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadPanelBar1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
       <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ButtonEnroll">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadPanelBar1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>

      <telerik:RadGrid ID="EnrollmentGrid" runat="server" Width="100%" GridLines="None"
            AllowPaging="True" ShowStatusBar="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="CourseCreditDS"
            OnItemCommand="EnrollmentGrid_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="EnrollmentGrid_ItemDataBound">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="pid" CommandItemDisplay="None">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn" HeaderStyle-Width="20px" />
                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" EditText="<%$ Resources: Manager, EditCredit %>"
                        Visible="false" />


                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AssignedColumn" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-Width="60px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Contents/Images/tick.gif" ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Manager, SessionAlreadyEnrolled %>" Visible='<%# Eval("enrolled").ToString() == "Y" %>' />
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Contents/Images/error.gif" ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Manager, SessionAlreadyEnrolledOther %>" Visible='<%# Eval("already_assigned").ToString() == "Y" %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Manager, StudentId %>" DataTextField="pid"
                        DataNavigateUrlFields="pid" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../Reporting/PivotView.aspx?id={0}"
                        SortExpression="pid" Target="_blank" />
                    <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Manager, Name %>" DataTextField="name"
                        DataNavigateUrlFields="pid" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../Reporting/PivotView.aspx?id={0}"
                        SortExpression="lname" Target="_blank" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Manager, Division %>" DataField="div_name"
                        SortExpression="div_name" />
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ResultColumn" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Manager, Result %>"
                        Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Literal ID="ResultText" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Manager, EmptyDataText %>" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="CapIdColumn" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Manager, CapId %>"
                        DataField="ot1" SortExpression="ot1" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" EmptyDataText="<%$ Resources: Manager, EmptyDataText %>"
                        Visible="false" />

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AttachColumn" Visible="false" HeaderText="Attachment">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="CCFileUploader"    runat="server" PostbackTriggers="btnUploadPost" OnFileUploaded="CCFileUploader_FileUploaded" OnClientFileUploaded="CCFileUploader_ClientFileUploaded" UploadedFilesRendering="BelowFileInput" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnUploadPost" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="hidden" Style="display: none" /></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="CCExistingUploadsLink" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Manager, NoExistingAttachments %>" Enabled="false" Style="text-decoration: none; color: #769e1a;" />
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="CCPid" runat="server" Visible="false" Value='<%# Eval("pid")%>' />
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </table>



                        </ItemTemplate>

                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                </Columns>
                <EditItemStyle CssClass="EditedItem" />
                <EditFormSettings UserControlName="~/Courses/Template/CourseCredit.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl">
                    <FormStyle BackColor="White" />
                </EditFormSettings>

            </MasterTableView>
            <ClientSettings>
                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" EnableDragToSelectRows="false" />
            </ClientSettings>
            <ExportSettings IgnorePaging="true" OpenInNewWindow="true">
                <Pdf PageHeight="297mm" PageWidth="210mm" PageTitle="Training Session" />
            </ExportSettings>
        </telerik:RadGrid>


          <telerik:RadGrid ID="EnrollListGrid" runat="server" Width="100%" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" ShowStatusBar="true" AllowMultiRowSelection="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDetailTableDataBind="EnrollListGrid_DetailTableDatabind"
            OnNeedDataSource="EnrollListGrid_OnNeedDataSource" OnPreRender="EnrollListGrid_OnPreRender">
            <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
            <MasterTableView AllowMultiColumnSorting="true" DataKeyNames="listname">
                <DetailTables>
                    <telerik:GridTableView DataKeyNames="pid" Name="DetailList">
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn" HeaderStyle-Width="20px">
                                <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                            </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AssignedColumn" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-Width="60px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Contents/Images/tick.gif" ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Manager, SessionAlreadyEnrolled %>" Visible='<%# Eval("enrolled").ToString() == "Y" %>' />
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Contents/Images/error.gif" ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Manager, SessionAlreadyEnrolledOther %>" Visible='<%# Eval("already_assigned").ToString() == "Y" %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Manager, StudentId %>" DataTextField="pid"
                                DataNavigateUrlFields="pid" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../Reporting/PivotView.aspx?id={0}"
                                SortExpression="pid" Target="_blank" />
                            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Manager, Name %>" DataTextField="name"
                                DataNavigateUrlFields="pid" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../Reporting/PivotView.aspx?id={0}"
                                SortExpression="lname" Target="_blank" />
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Manager, Division %>" DataField="div_name"
                                SortExpression="div_name" />

                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="CapIdColumn" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Manager, CapId %>"
                                DataField="ot1" SortExpression="ot1" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" EmptyDataText="<%$ Resources: Manager, EmptyDataText %>" />
                        </Columns>


                        <EditItemStyle CssClass="EditedItem" />
                        <EditFormSettings UserControlName="~/Courses/Template/CourseCredit.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl">
                            <FormStyle BackColor="White" />
                        </EditFormSettings>

                    </telerik:GridTableView>
                </DetailTables>
                <Columns>
                    <%--<telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectList" ></telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>--%>
                    <%--<telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="EnrollListID" HeaderText="Enroll List ID" DataField="listid"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>--%>
                    <%--<telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="ViewListItems" EditText="View List Items"  ></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>--%>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="EnrollListName" HeaderText="Enroll List Name" DataField="listname"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>

            </MasterTableView>
            <ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true">
                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" EnableDragToSelectRows="false" />
                <%--<ClientEvents OnRowSelecting="EnrollListGrid_OnRowSelecting" />--%>
            </ClientSettings>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Please let me know if u need the code behind

Comment: Sound like an ajaxification problem, can you post some RadAjaxManager code?

Comment: RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this).ClientEvents.OnRequestStart = "requestStart";

Comment: So you have a custom javascript method also. Can you post more code on your question? The error can be on the 2 RadGrid code, the code behind postback or in the custom javascript.

Comment: Can't see the ajaxification of the filter button on the grid, and the ajaxification of the select button on the other grid. But maybe I haven't understand because i can't see grid and button code.

Comment: Its seems GridClientSelectColumn not working for the first time before the button is clicked.Please check the code above.Have modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ajaxify the source of the binding (i think it's the filtered grid) to the destination of the binding (the second grid).

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="EnrollmentGrid">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="EnrollListGrid" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Let me know if it help. Otherwise i really need a simpler working version of your code...